# The image I upload to my Laravel saved as a folder

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to upload an image from Postman the image I send is saved in a storage folder But it is shown as a folder not (PNG,jpg...),
this is my upload image code :

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
 {
    $request->validate([
        'photo' => 
      'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $photo = $request->file('photo');
    $photoName = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
    $photoPath = public_path('storage/' . $photoName);
    $photo->move($photoPath);
    $imagePath = $photoPath;
    $model = new Image();
    $model->image_path = $imagePath;
    $model->save();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Image uploaded successfully!',
        'image_path' => $imagePath,
    ]);
}
```

and when opened the link shows was not found on this server.
[image]

[image]

when i put the image in storage directory manually the image show in brawser

Comment: The definition is `move(string $directory, string $name = null)`, so you're missing the filename portion of the command. It can rewrite the name with the base name, but apparently it's unable to get that properly. You're also adding the photo filename to the directory path.

Comment: `$photoPath = public_path('storage/' . $photoName);` - you are using the name the file had on the client as name of your _folder_ here already. So of course you _get_ a folder named same as the image file, when you are explicitly _asking_ the system to do that.

Comment: Why not follow the Laravel [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#file-uploads) documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one.

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request){
    /*
        image validation
    */
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $photoName = str_replace(' ', '', $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName());
        $request->photo->move(public_path('storage'), $photoName);
        $photoPath = '/storage/' . $photoName; // get saved image path

        // if you want full image path with url
        // $fullPath = url('/') . $photoPath; // get full image path with url
        
        /*
            Do your model Work
        */
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Image uploaded successfully',
            'image_path' => $photoPath // you can also send full image path
        ]);
    }else{
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Something went wrong!',
        ]);
    }
}
```